# Want to sort the records according to day of week?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a field name session_dayofweek in the database which stores day name like for example 'Mon'. I want to get the records sorted by the session_dayofweek. The records should be sorted like Sun, Mon, Tue etc. starting from sunday. I am running the query on wordpress database.

Here is my query:

```
$wpdb->pre_assignments = $wpdb->prefix . 'tc_pre_assignments';
$get_session_name=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->pre_assignments.*,$wpdb->sessions.* FROM $wpdb->pre_assignments JOIN $wpdb->sessions on $wpdb->pre_assignments.session_id = $wpdb->sessions.session_id WHERE $wpdb->sessions.session_id='".$session_id."'");
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I'd have used int for day of the week, beginning with 0 = sunday.

Comment: @user3791372 the thing is the table already exists in another application so i am just importing the data from the same file my client gave me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a conditional order by

```
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Sun' THEN 1
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Mon' THEN 2
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Tue' THEN 3
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Wed' THEN 4
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Thu' THEN 5
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Fri' THEN 6
   WHEN session_dayofweek = 'Sat' THEN 7
   ELSE 8
END
```

if you are looking for a pattern sort (aka sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun, mon, tue.. etc) you could do something like this

```
ORDER BY assignment_id, FIELD(session_dayofweek,'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat')
```

[sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cd9/1)

Comment: yes i am looking for a pattern sort but its still not working here is the query i am trying
SELECT $wpdb->pre_assignments.*,$wpdb->sessions.* FROM $wpdb->pre_assignments JOIN $wpdb->sessions on $wpdb->pre_assignments.session_id = $wpdb->sessions.session_id WHERE $wpdb->sessions.session_id='".$session_id."' ORDER BY FIELD(session_dayofweek,'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');

Comment: @NitinJohnson saying something isn't working doesn't really help much. can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: what i mean is its returning records is the same format it was returning before like 'wed', 'fri','thu' while it should return 'wed','thu' and then 'fri'

Comment: @NitinJohnson what does the data look like? are you trying to order assignments by when they were turned in?

Comment: @NitinJohnson you need to include a common item to the order by. so like if you have an assignment_id and multiple submissions on different days, then you `order by assignment_id, field(...)` [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cd9/1)

Comment: well i am joining two tables sessions and assignments and trying to sort the session based on the session_dayofweek field. Here is the screenshot of how the final data looks:

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/310044/5PdfV2KKCQmanNSxEflA22WnSQMzdFDg/

Comment: @NitinJohnson order by field should work for that. it would group it. try running a simple query off of the session table without joining with that order by. after that maybe try `ORDER BY session, FIELD(session_dayofweek,'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat')`

Comment: @NitinJohnson what does the data look like with your join?

Comment: if you want to see the screenshot pls check the above link i provided you.

Comment: @NitinJohnson is that screenshot the query with the table already joined?

Comment: @NitinJohnson then the issue is not with the query but with how its executed. is there a way you can print out the actual query before it runs? i think something with the quotes for that FIELD() is getting messed up. maybe try double quotes

Comment: no its not an issue with the quotes the thing is its returning the result if it was an issue with the query then it would have thrown an error. Anyway here is the new query i made as you suggested

$get_session_name=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->pre_assignments.*,$wpdb->sessions.* FROM $wpdb->pre_assignments JOIN $wpdb->sessions on $wpdb->pre_assignments.session_id = $wpdb->sessions.session_id WHERE $wpdb->sessions.session_id='".$session_id."' ORDER BY $wpdb->sessions.session_dayofweek, FIELD($wpdb->sessions.session_dayofweek,'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');");

Comment: @NitinJohnson yea i dont know why that is happening.. you can see from the sql fiddle I added that it is ordering it. maybe its a wordpress thing.